# MATLAB While loop syntax

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I'm using the code

```
 k = 0;
 while k<3
 k = k+1;
 a = 5^k;
 disp(a);
 end
```

however, when the result outputs it only gives me the answer of one iteration. I'm wondering what the difference is to the computer when you use this code instead:

```
 clear, clc
 k = 0;
 while k<3
 k = k+1;
 a(k) = 5^k;
 end
 disp(a)
```

Why does the first code sample output only 125, while the second one outputs 5, 25, and 125?

Comment: are you sure that the first code result is 125 ?

Comment: I get `[5;25; 125]`, and `[5,25,125]` for the two codes. Why are you doing `while` rather than `for`?

Comment: You may want to read the [getting started document](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_version/learnmatlab.pdf)

Comment: I was using code that was displayed for an example in an engineering computing textbook. They used this example to demonstrate while loops.

Comment: And thanks. I'll check out that document!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first code, variable `a` is scalar. 
So, Matlab erases and re-writes value into variable `a` in every iteration.

But, in case of second code, as you defined array index `k` at variable `a`, Matlab understands your variable `a(k)` as array variable. And, in every iteration, Matlab writes the assigned value `5^k` on corresponding array point.

Comment: thanks, that's a great interpretation and explanation!